# RAL colour for Metallic PMS 8923

Tags: print-design

Has anybody converted from Metallic PMS 8923 to a RAL colour, or closest to!

Answer (score 2):

Google search your question shows PMS 8932 equals RAL 3020.

Complex color coder conversions best handled by internet search.

Do not expect someone to have these conversions in their head.
http://rgb.to/c70700